# Alpha channel not responding to blur?

Tags: rendering, camera, transparency, blur

Here is a still of a shallow focused camera of a few flowers. As you can see the pink flower alpha blend is not responding to the blur... How do I ensure it is blurring like the rest of them?

[image]